# expose internal events polymer

Tags: events, polymer

I am trying to make custom file input

```
 <dom-module id="paper-file-input">
       <template>  
         <paper-input id="name" label="File" readonly></paper-input>
         <input type="file" id="file" class="inputfile" on-change="">
         <label for="file">
           <paper-icon-button icon="menu">
           </paper-icon-button>
         </label>
       </template>
       <script>
         Polymer({
          is: 'paper-file-input'
         })
       </script>
</dom-module>
```

is it possible to expose local dom events such as `event.target.files`

Comment: What do you mean by `inside the element`? `on-change` case reads as when `change` event is fired from `paper-file-input` execute mentioned function in calling element

Comment: I think you should read the documentation: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events